# cx_Oracle fail to connect to one database using different machine

Tags: python-2.7, cx-oracle

I am trying to connect to ORACLE database using cx_Oracle with python.
Code shown below. Same code able to connect to target database while running on a pc, however not able to connect using a server.
Error message: ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist

Since it can be connected use other pc, I think should not be the password or service name wrong.
The server having issue connecting to the database is a linux, with cx_Oracle installed, and ORACLE_HOME, LD_LIBRARY_PATH defined.

Any one can give a hint on what might goes wrong?

### code used

```
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('Host Name', 'Port Number', service_name='ServiceName') 
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'UserName', password='Password', dsn=dsn_tns) 
c = conn.cursor()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out it was due to network access issue.